# GNU Parallel not work (parallel_20120422-1_a in Ubuntu 16.04.5)

Tags: gnu-parallel

- I use parallel_20120422-1_a in Ubuntu 16.04.5. It was used to run very well.
- But recently, even `"parallel --version"` dose not work. After I typed `"parallel --version"` and return, no response at all and stuck.
- I re-install parallel_20120422-1_a again `"sudo apt install parallel"`.

It dose the same. Might anyone provide me some suggestions to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try running `type parallel` to see if you have aliased it, or made a function of it, or what you are actually running.

Comment: Or very simply install a brand new, current version instead of the old stuff your package manager is giving you http://oletange.blogspot.com/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: $ type parallel
parallel is /usr/bin/parallel
It is there. Thank @Mark Setchell very much for your quick response!

Comment: Try `parallel -Dall echo ::: 1` and post the output from that.